# The math behind dragging a map around in a game

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop

Had a hard time finding examples of this online, so I thought I'd share a problem I'd had and how I fixed it. I was unsure of how to use a "drag" feature to move a map around. I wanted to be able to scroll around the map by dragging the screen, similar to Farmville, Boom Beach, or even Civilization and games like that. Most drag-and-drop features are only concerned with making sure the draggable object follows the mouse for the duration of the drag and then set it down later. But, simply snapping the map object to the mouse will not allow you to scroll beyond the screen edges, as our mouse/touch will only ever go that far. What we need is a way to get the mouse/touch position relative to the object we're dragging, so that the object we're dragging does not snap or relocate to the center of the mouse.

So how does one implement their own dragging system in as3?

Answer (score 0):

This answer should, hopefully, help you understand the math behind the operation. Setting up the mouse events is another issue. The one I use here is unique to my system. I wanted to provide the operation of setting the object's position without the clutter of event listeners and other things required to set up mouse events

```
public var mouseLast:Point = null;
public var mouseNow:Point = new Point();        
public var mouseDown:Boolean = false;
public function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    mouseDown = false;
} 
public function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    mouseLast = mouseNow.clone();   
    mouseNow.setTo(e.stageX, e.stageY); 
    if (mouseDown)
    {

        objectToDrag.x += mouseNow.x - mouseLast.x;
        objectToDrag.y += mouseNow.y - mouseLast.y;

    }

}

public function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    mouseDown = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it doesn't make sense to always listen out for mouse moves, and only act if the mouse is down. instead add a mouse move listener on mouse down, and remove it on mouse up. something like below

```js
private var mouesOffset = new Point();

public function Test()
{
    map.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
}

protected function onMouseDown(e:*)
{
    mouseOffset.x = map.mouseX * map.scaleX;
    mouseOffset.y = map.mouseY * map.scaleY;

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(e:*)
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, arguments.callee);
    });
}

private function onMouseMove(e:*)
{
    map.x = mouseX - mouseOffset.x;
    map.y = mouseY - mouseOffset.y;
}
```

Comment: There are other things in my code that need doing as the mouse moves whether or not the mouse is down. That's why I specified that the answer I gave was specific to the math rather than the listeners